# Problem with list index out of range due to addr+1 not append

Tags: python

I have defined two functions hitorMiss and combinedCache
The code is as follows:

```
def hitOrMiss(addr):
    storeAddr= addr # store the address into the local variable
    offset=int(math.log(blockSize, 2)) # calculating offset
    indexValue = int(math.log(cacheSize / (associativity * blockSize), 2))  # calculating index
    # addrLength = np.uint32(storeAddr) # converting address length to 32

    addrLength=32
    tag = addrLength - offset - indexValue # getting tag value 
    flag1 = int(('1' * tag + '0' * indexValue + '0' * offset), 2)# select tag value and make 0 for index and offset  
    tag = (storeAddr & flag1) >> (indexValue + offset)  # shif the tag
    flag2 = int(('0' * indexValue + '1' * indexValue+ '0' * offset), 2)# select index value and make 0 for tag and offset
    index = (storeAddr & flag2) >> (offset)  # shift the index

    if associativity==1: # check for associativity if 1 direct mapping
        if tag == cacheArray[index]:
            return 1;# if equal return  1 that means set so compare tag
        else: 
            stride=0
            confidence=0
            newaddr=0
            prefetch.append(tag)

            stride= abs(prefetch[addr]-prefetch[addr+1])
```

```
def combinedCache(unified):
    hits = 0;# initialize hit and miss
    miss = 0;

    for addr in unified:
        if hitOrMiss(addr) is 1:  # call a function for hit or miss

            hits += 1  # increment hits
        else:

            miss = miss + 1  # increment misses
    return hits, miss
```

I am getting error as list out of range in hitormiss function when i subtract two elements from list.I know list at 1st element is not currently present that's why it is showing error but while initialization i have initialized in this way prefetch=[0] I am new to python programming please help me with the solution.Thank you!!

Comment: error in line stride=abs(prefetch[addr]-prefetch[addr+1])

Comment: Well, there is no item at `addr+1` in your list. What are the values for `prefetch` and `addr`?

Comment: sir, prefetch is an empty list and I am appending it in hitormiss function and I have called hitormiss function in combinedCache through which it is getting addresss@luigigi

Comment: you said you initialized `prefetch=[0]` so it cant be empty. Then you append a value and you got two elements in it. so your calculation can only work if `addr=0`

Comment: you have to check if your values for `addr` are right. if `addr >= len(prefetch)` your calculation cant work

Comment: @BhavinThakar, show the content of `unified` as well